# OpenLayers 3 Popup customization issues

Tags: openlayers, css

I have an OpenLayers cluster map. I want to create a customized popup as follows:

[image]

The problem I'm facing is auto-pan doesn't work

```
var popup = new ol.Overlay(//** @type {olx.OverlayOptions} *//*
({
    element : container,
    autoPan : true,
    autoPanAnimation : {
        duration : 250
    }
}));
```

**i.e if I click on a cluster on the border of the visible view the screen doesn't adjust to fit the popup rather the popup gets cut.**

[image]

- **Second issue** I'm facing is the popup width, I want to give the popup a responsive width

  i.e. it should have a width in relation to its content but it gets scrunched up. I've tried giving it in % but only hard coded px width works.

**I want to give it responsive width, with a min width beyond which it should not go**

- **Third issue** I'm facing is if my popup has a lot of data I'm showing a scroller by using:

  `.popover-content {overflow-y: scroll;}`

**How do I customize the scroll bar??**

[image]

- cluster map js file: http://pastebin.com/XamgaYHC
- HTML file: http://pastebin.com/M0ncX3hV
- css file: http://pastebin.com/QnjnUv1N

Comment: Could you put this altogether in a jsFiddle? It's so much easier to deal with.

Comment: As per the [tour] there should be only one question asked (or one issue raised) per question.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issues discussed here.
For Second one, please do not assign any value for width parameter in css,it will take responsive size automatically.